# Padrão de repositório em aplicações legadas - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, design-pattern

Estou participando de um projeto utilizando ASP.NET MVC 5, gostaria de opiniões para eu formar um conceito no qual eu possa realizar bons resultados com uma boa produtividade da equipe.

#### O que tenho de interfaces:

- IRepository
- ICacheRepository
- ICacheService
- IUnitOfWork

#### As implementações das interfaces:

- Repository : `IRepository`
- CacheRepository: `Repository`, `ICacheRepository`
- InMemoryCache : `ICacheService`

`Repository.cs`

```cs
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        public MyDatabaseContext context;

        public Repository(MyDatabaseContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> All()
        {
            return this.context.Set<T>().AsQueryable<T>();
        }

        public T Find(int id)
        {
            return this.context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }
    }
```

`CacheRepository.cs`

```cs
    public class CacheRepository<T> : Repository<T>, ICacheRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly ICacheService cacheService;

        public CacheRepository(MyDatabaseContext context, ICacheService cacheService) : base(context)
        {
            this.cacheService = cacheService;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> All()
        {
            return this.cacheService.GetOrSet<IEnumerable<T>>($"{typeof(T)}", () => base.All());
        }

        public T Find(int id)
        {
            return this.cacheService.GetOrSet<T>($"{typeof(T)}.{id}", () => base.Find(id));
        }
    }
```

#### Quanto a parte do UnitOfWork:

Tenho a implementação do UnitOfWork centralizando as partes, utilizei um exemplo do método de `GetCacheRepository<T>()` para demonstrar como eu retornarei os repositórios já com o Context e CacheService (no caso de repositório que pode ter cache).

```cs
    public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork where TContext : MyDatabaseContext, new()
    {
        private readonly MyDatabaseContext DataContext;
        protected readonly ICacheService cacheService;
        private Dictionary<Type, object> repositories;
        private Dictionary<Type, object> cacheRepositories;

        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            this.DataContext = new TContext();
            this.cacheService = new InMemoryCache();
            this.repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
            this.cacheRepositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        }

        /* Método duplicado para exemplificação */
        public ICacheRepository<T> GetCacheRepository<T>() where T: class
        {
            if (!this.cacheRepositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)))
            {
                var repository = new CacheRepository<T>(this.DataContext, this.cacheService);

                this.cacheRepositories.Add(typeof(T), repository);
            }

            return this.cacheRepositories[typeof(T)] as ICacheRepository<T>;
        }

        /* Método duplicado para exemplificação */
        public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
        {
            if (!this.repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)))
            {
                var repository = new Repository<T>(this.DataContext);

                this.repositories.Add(typeof(T), repository);
            }

            return this.repositories[typeof(T)] as IRepository<T>;
        }
    }
```

#### Como o serviço utiliza:

```cs
    public class SampleService
    {
        protected readonly IUnitOfWork uow;
        protected readonly IRepository<MyModel> MyRepository;
        protected readonly ICacheRepository<MyModelEnum> MyCacheRepository;

        public SampleService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            this.uow = uow;

            this.MyRepository = this.uow.GetRepository<MyModel>();
            this.MyCacheRepository = this.uow.GetRepository<MyModelEnum>();
        }

        public MyModel FindById(int id)
        {
           return this.MyRepository.Find(1);
        }

        public IEnumerable<MyModelEnum> GetEnum()
        {
           return this.MyCacheRepository.All();
        }

    }
```

#### Como o Ninject injeta a dependência:

```cs
   kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork<MyDatabaseContext>>();
```

esse cenário foi projetado para a discursão com os usuários, não existe respota certa ou errada, quero opiniões diversas, obrigado!

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida e o que a questão tem a ver com o asp.net-mvc-5?

Comment: Minha dúvida/questionamento e quanto a utilização de UnitOfWork e padrão de repositorio e serviço em aplicações ASP.NET MVC 5, gostaria de abordagem e ideias de pessoas que utilizam a stack semelhante.